# Django Queryset sort by order_by with relatedManager

Tags: python, database, django, django-related-manager

I am tryint to get objects sorted. this is my code:

```
ratings = Rate.objects.order_by(sortid)
locations = Location.objects.filter(locations_rate__in=ratings).order_by('locations_rate').distinct('id')
```

this is my model:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
  von_location= models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_rate")
  price_leistung = models.IntegerField(max_length=5,default=00)
  bewertung = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,default=00)
```

how can I get all Locations in that order which is equal to that of `ratings`?

what I have above isnot working.
**EDIT**:

```
def sort(request):
  sortid = request.GET.get('sortid')
  ratings = Rate.objects.all()
  locations = Location.objects.filter(locations_rate__in=ratings).order_by('locations_rate__%s' % sortid).distinct('id')
  if request.is_ajax():
    template = 'resultpart.html'
    return render_to_response(template,{'locs':locations},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: @PavelAnossov, it is either ``price_leistung`` or ``bewertung``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify a field to use for sorting the `Rate` objects, for example:

```
ratings = Rate.objects.all()
locations = Location.objects.filter(
    locations_rate__in=ratings
).order_by('locations_rate__%s' % sortid).distinct('id')
```

You do not need to sort `ratings` beforehand.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) provides example of use of `order_by` on related fields.

Comment: thanks, but it is saying. ``The view home.views.sort didn't return an HttpResponse object.``. something is wrong in this query.

Comment: I believe that's another question :) Your view need to return some data, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/). You should post your view code if you need more help on this point

Comment: I am returning this as ajax response, i am rendering some html part with data rendered inside. so HttpResponse shouldnot be there. please see my view in my update

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to me, `render_to_response` will return an `HttpResponse `. I guess the `request.is_ajax()` evaluates to `False` in your view then, are you sure you're accessing it through an AJAX call? Also, even if your view only supports AJAX requests, you should handle all types of response, for example return `HttpResponseBadRequest` or ` for non-AJAX requests, this will help debugging.

Comment: I am using Jquery load,  i think, this is the reason.